# Azure Information protection-AIPScanner-Set-AIPAuthentication : Error acquiring token

Tags: entra-id

I am facing an issue while configuring the AIP scanner service.

I have followed the following two articles: [AIP scanner setup](https://github.com/kemckinnmsft/HOL3000/blob/master/instructions-web.md#aip-scanner-setup), [Installation Configuration and usage of the AIP scanner](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Information-Protection/Installation-Configuration-and-Usage-of-the-AIP-Scanner/ba-p/221792)

As I worked through the steps I had faced the following issue and can not move forward.

While I run the following command:

```
Set-AIPAuthentication -WebAppID f2e496d7-2f7a-49ea-989a-7ea81454fb84 -WebAppKey b2a29c53-4bfe-45fb-8f93-70a28bc57ef1 -NativeAppID 6eadbfeb-482b-4c19-88ce-b0bcd971b146
```

I receive the following error:

[image]

```
Set-AIPAuthentication : Error acquiring token
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AIPAuthentication -WebAppID f2e496d7-2f7a-49ea-989a-7ea81454fb84  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (:) [Set-AIPAuthentication], PowershellException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.InformationProtection.Powershell.AIP.Commandlets.SetAIPAuthenticationCmdLet
```

I have already allowed the cookies in IE and Chrome and checked that Azure rights management is activated.
Host machine is Windows 2012 R2 and AIP client is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I was able to get around it by logging into the desktop as the AIP service account then running the Set-AIPAuthentication command.  I also temporarily turned off Enhanced Internet Explorer security.